# Calling a function in code behind by using an imagebutton in a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calling a functon in code behind by using an imagebutton in a gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903141/calling-a-functon-in-code-behind-by-using-an-imagebutton-in-a-gridview)

I have an ImageButton within a gridview in .aspx on clicking this imagebutton i have to call a function.
This is how i tried and the function was not being called.
Code inside.aspx page:

```
<GridView ......>
    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server"  NavigateUrl='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"VehID","mngVeh.aspx?delid={0}") %>'>   
                                                         <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="DeleteUrlImageButton" ImageUrl="~/images/delete.jpeg" width='24' height='24'
                                                                          OnClick="DeleteUrlImageButton_Click"
                                                                          OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?');" />


   </asp:HyperLink>
</GridView>
```

code in .aspx.cs page:

```
public void DeleteUrlImageButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //code to perform the necessary action.
}
```

Comment: Accept some answers and don't ask the same questions again, instead edit the original question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're mixing controls up here.

I would use an ImageUrl on the asp:hyperlink itself, and also the OnClick property. You can handle the OnClientClick by using javascript inside the NavigateUrl property.

I don't see a reason for having a nested ImageButton - I doubt this even works.

Or, just remove the asp:hyperlink completely and do a redirect inside the OnClick event.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is twofold:  First, the click event does not bubble up through the `GridView`, which is why the event is not firing.  Second, that there will be an `ImageButton` for each row of the `GridView`, and you need to identify which row the event originated from (or more accurately, which underlying datasource record that row corresponds to).

A common way to approach this problem is to use the `ImageButton.CommandName` and `ImageButton.CommandArgument` properties, and handle the `GridView.RowCommand` event.

Markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="DeleteUrlImageButton" ImageUrl="~/images/delete.jpeg"
                            Width='24' Height='24' OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?');"
                            CommandName="MyDelete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("RecordId") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Code:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.CommandName == "MyDelete") && (e.CommandArgument != null))
    {

        //Add delete code here using e.CommandArgument to identify the correct record.
        //  For instance:
        MyDataObject obj = new MyDataObject();
        obj.RecordId = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
        MyDataObject.Delete(obj);
    }
}
```

Edit: I see you provided the name of the ID field in your example, so you would probably want to replace "RecordId" in my example with "VehID".

Comment: Hi pseudocoder ,could you explain your code . I didnt understand why you are using  MyDataObject (what is MyDataObject ?)How do i get the ID ?

Comment: @gnome123 MyDataObject is an example of a Data Accesss Layer (DAL) class you might create in order to hold your database access code, typically in a series of static methods (for instance MyDataObject.Delete()).  It would also define properties that map to fields in a db table (for instance RecordId).

Comment: @gnome123 As far as getting the ID, I'm assuming you have your GridView bound to a datasource which will provide a list of ID values to work with.  The CommandArgument passes the ID value from the GridView to your RowCommand procedure.  Hopefully this helps, but covering these topics is kind of hard to do in this comment section.  I'd recommend searching for information on Data Access Layers to get more in-depth.